# httppost failure to display in modal bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, http-post

I am using Bootstrap modal and I have built modal using the link: http://codepen.io/elmahdim/details/azVNbN

Everything works fine except when I called the [httppost] and something wents wrong in the action like posted email is wrong or doesnot exist then I want to display the error back on the modal.
Instead of displaying the error on the modal it display in the broken new page.

_Layout.cshtml

```
<div class="modal fade" id="log-in" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    @Html.Action("Login","User")
</div>
```

_Login.cshtml

```
@model FrontEnd.Models.LoginModel
@{
    var result = ViewBag.ResultModel;
}
@using Web.FrontEnd.Common

<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>   
        </div>


@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "User", FormMethod.Post,
                    new AjaxOptions

                {

                    HttpMethod = "POST",
                    UpdateTargetId = "#log-in"// Modal id as mention in //_layout.cshtml

                }, new { @id = "loginUser", @class = "modal-form" }))
    {
            <div class="modal-body">
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                @if (result.IsVisible)
                {
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.Raw(@result.Message)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Email", autocomplete = "off" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Password", autocomplete = "off" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
                            <input type="hidden" name="LastPage" id="LastPage" value="@ViewBag.LastPage" />

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#google-login" data-dismiss="modal">< Back</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">Log In</button>
                        <button type="button" class="linkButton" style="color: red" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reset-password" data-dismiss="modal">Forgot Password?</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

UserController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string LastPage)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      // Code to add database
    }
    //something went wrong then show on modal?
    return this.PartialView("_Login",model);
}
```

Comment: If you want the login form in a modal, you need to use ajax to post the form so that you stay on the same page and can update the DOM with the returned error message or partial view of the form.

Comment: I tried but may be I am setting something wrong probably Updatetargetid

Comment: _I tried_? Tried what? We cant guess what you have done wrong.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Updated the ajax code..Please check and let me know...Thanks

Comment: If `return PartialView("_Login",model);` is redirecting you to a new page, then it means you have not included the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script in the main view (or layout)

Comment: 1. Tried Installing 
Install-Package Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax
gaved me 
error install-Package : Updating 'jQuery 2.1.0' to 'jQuery 1.8.2' failed. Unable to find a version of 'bootstrap' that is compatible with 'jQuery 1.8.2'.
2. However after forceful installation it worked for me.
a. Added unobtrusive ajax
b. UpdateTargetId = "log-in" from UpdateTargetId = "#log-in"

Comment: You should not need to install it. It will be in you Scripts folder by default.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: It wasn't there for me, though :o

Comment: Then you will need to make sure you packages you install are compatible